# Flask send_from_directory for media files

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a small Flask application destined from home network use.

At the moment I have Flask running with uWSGI and nginx.

The app basically scans a location and serves media files. Below is the code for rendering these files:

```
@app.route('/get_media/<path:filename>', methods=['GET'])
    def get_media(filename):
        return send_from_directory('/media/', filename)
```

The `send_from_directory` works fine, but seems to be slow. I must admit I don't really understand the process behind it. Is python serving these files or is nginx? I want nginx to be able to server these files, but I'm unsure how to configure the alias as I want the app to walk the directories of the files but would like to handoff the serving to nginx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already using nginx you should serve media and static files using nginx, no reason to serve them with uWSGI and flask, too much overhead.

```
#in case you have structure /path/to/your/media_dir/media
location /media {
   root /path/to/your/media_dir;
}

#in case you have structure /path/to/your/media_dir
location /media {
   alias /path/to/your/media_dir;
}
```

Comment: So you should not do what you do now. You also should remove handlers from flask, no need in them

Comment: During development I don't use nginx. How can I get the images to appear but still use nginx when in production?

Comment: Flask should serve files from same location as nginx, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/#static-files, in development files will be server by flask, in production directly by nginx before reaching flask for urls that reside in same path

Comment: How can I make those served files secure? Currently my flask app serves from directory in DEV environment, but only through a route with @login_required decorator. If I move to production and serve through nginx, wouldn't my files then become accessible to anyone?

Comment: there is no simple answer, very depends on how secure you want it to be. And first of all you need to consider, whether it really need to be secure. Often it only seems so, but in practice, URLs that not easy to guess is pretty enough. And if it is really need to be secured, there is a plenty of options, but none is single or best. Pre-generated credentials for nginx, pre-signed url for S3 - both can, theoretically leak, url will be accessible to anyone who gets it.... And then it leaves with what you are doing and flavours of it. Bust best to reconsider, non-obvious url + https usually good